# PHP Modal edit data from table

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have one modal for creating new record in table and table like:
[image: Table from mysql]

Code for table was:

```
  <?
    $sql = 'select * from katalog';
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $baza);
    $provjera = mysql_num_rows($result);
    php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    if ($provjera == ''){
    echo '<td>Nemate otvorenih kataloga.</td>';
    }else if ($provjera != ''){?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['naziv']; ?></td>
    td><?php
    $status = $row['status'];
    if ($status == '1'){
    echo 'Aktivno';
    }else if ($status == '0'){
    echo 'Neaktivno'; }    echo '<td><a href="#uredimodal" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-  effect waves-light orange modal-trigger" data-naziv="daa" data-status="'.$status.'"><i class="material-icons" style="color:white">mode_edit</i></a>|  
   <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red modal-trigger" href="#obrisiuredimodal" ><i class="material-icons" style="color:white">delete</i> Obriši</td></a>';
    ?><?php }} ?></td>
```

From code you see that I need when I click on orange edit button open some other module with data. How can I edit some data from table with MODAL?
Table and modal is in same PHP file.

Code for modal:

```
<!-- Modal Editiranje -->
<div id="uredimodal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Uredi Katalog <?php echo $naziv;?></h4>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <label for="email" class="">Naslov Kataloga</label>
                <input id="naslov" name="naslov" class="required validate" aria-required="true" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['naziv']; ?>" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <div class="select-wrapper"><span class="caret">▼</span><input class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-cde9ce7d-c5d2-8deb-ad2c-e8a5668916c4" value="Choose your option" style="" type="text"><ul id="select-options-cde9ce7d-c5d2-8deb-ad2c-e8a5668916c4" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 458px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
                                        <li class=""><span>Aktivno</span></li>
                                        <li class=""><span>Neaktivno</span></li></ul>
                                        <select id="status" name="status" class="initialized">
                                            <option value="1">Akivno</option>
                                            <option value="0">Neaktivno</option>
                                        </select></div>
                                        <label>Odaberite status kataloga</label>
                                    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" style="float:right;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn m-b-xs"><i class="material-icons left">input</i>Spremi</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Question is unclear. Code Is messy and unreadable.  If you want an answer you need to edit your question.

Comment: On a side note to avoid mess like that in code separate logic from presentation(html form PHP) or use template libraries. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/ or https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php or any other

Comment: Code is more readable but question is still unclear. On click you want  a modal where you edit things and than when you save it table changes ?